# How popular is 'brefass' in modern American vocabulary?

Tags: phrases, american-english, abbreviations, dialects, eye-dialect

This is an abbreviation of 'breakfast' that I have found myself paying extra attention to recently. In fact I have even heard my mother use it on a regular basis. Is this common in modern spoken American vocabulary, or is this purely the construct of a regional dialect? We are native speakers from the Great Lakes region of The United States.

Other words that fall under the same category:

- "I don't know" == *dunno*
- "kitchen"      == *kinna*   (rare)
- "library"      == *Libary*  (With an extra accent on the 'i', L-EYE-barry)
- "school"       == *skoo*
- "jewelry"      == *joo-ry*
- "math"         == *maff*
- "Italian" == *Italian* (With an extra accent on the 'i' instead of the first 'a', EYE-talian)

Comment: I've never heard brefass, kinna, skoo, joo-ry, or maff from anyone over the age of about four (unless there's a speech impediment involved).  Other "collapsed" mispronunciations I've heard: "prolly" for "probably" and"sammich" for "sandwich", both of which I've only become aware of in the last decade.

Comment: Sure, there are all sorts of standard words that are written one way, but hardly ever pronounced in one-to-one correspondence with the spelling. In fact, that's a particularly boring truism about English orthography, well, also about any language's orthography. Consonant clusters tend to get simplified in speech. 'Wasps' tends to get pronounced without the 'p'. '-nd-' tends to get pronounced '-n-'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm from New England, and I've only ever heard *brefass/breffis* out of the mouth of a little kid who couldn't pronounce *breakfast.* As for the others, *dunno* is common in many dialects; I've never heard *kinna* before (except as an alteration of *cannot),* so it's probably local; *lie-barry* is a fairly common minority (mis)pronunciation, especially in urban accents; and both *skoo* and *jewry* are an effect of articulating [ l ] as [ w ], which happens largely word-finally or after [ u ], also mostly in urban accents.

Comment: I would assume the same in regards to the usage of 'brefass' by children, but I was recently having breakfast with several other adults and nearly every person at the table commented 'This is a really great place to get brefass. We should come here more often.'

Comment: @bakoyaro: The closest I get, even being really lazy, is [bɹɛhfəst]. *Brefass* (at least the way I'm reading it) sounds too much like *preface*.

Comment: I'd tend to think of *lib'ry*, too, as a reduction rather than a specific variant (mis)pronunciation.  The two r's close together seem to be tricky to articulate; *February* gets the same treatment, very very rarely being pronounced with two r's.  I can't think of any other words with similar endings to explore this end further, though...